# How to extract data from a Wikipedia article?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have a question regarding parsing data from Wikipedia for my Android app. I have a script that can download the XML by reading the source from `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&format=xml&page=ARTICLE_NAME` (and also the JSON by replacing `format=xml` with `format=json`.

But what I can't figure out is how to only access certain sections from the table of contents. What I want is when the page is loaded, the user can press a button that makes a pop-up appear that displays the headers from the table of contents and allow the user to read that piece and only that piece of it for convenience. I'm a little shaky with JSON but is it possible to do this? Or, is there an API from Wikipedia that allows the developer to only view certain parts of a page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it seems [the mediawiki.org documentation for `parse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse) doesn't tell you how to do this. But [the documentation in the API itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) does: You can use `section` parameter. And you can use `prop=sections` to get the list of sections.

So, you could first use:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Android_%28operating_system%29&prop=sections

to get the list of sections and then

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Android_%28operating_system%29&prop=text&section=26

to get the HTML for a certain section.

Answer (score 2):

action=parse doesn't work well with per-section parse, consider this shoert example:

```
Foo is a bar<ref>really!</ref>
== References ==
<references/>
```

Parsing just the zeroth section will result in red error message about  without  while parsing the first one will result in empty references list.

However, there's a better solution: [action=mobileview](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=mobileview) is not only free from this problem, but it's also specifically intended for mobile apps and gives you mobile-optimized HTML.

Comment: I looked into this, and I run into problems with it. If you look at this code: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Android_%28operating_system%29&prop=text&section=10 it gives you the info contained in the section, but if you look at it with action=mobileview, it gives you a blank page.

Comment: I haven't seen any working example for action=mobileview. Can you give us one?